# Unable to connect to the Simple HTTPS Server

Tags: python, python-2.x

I copied the code from below location:

**https://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/**

And created new pem file like below:

```
sh-3.2# openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 10
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.......................+++
...............................+++
writing new private key to 'key.pem'
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [GB]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Berkshire]:CA
Locality Name (eg, city) [Newbury]:CA
Organization Name (eg, company) [My Company Ltd]:Test
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Test
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:mybox.com
Email Address []:me@test.com
```

It created 2 files cert.pem and key.pem. So my final code was:

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='/myhome/cert.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And I ran my program:

```
python myserver.py
```

But when I try to access it from browser:

```
https://mybox.com:4443
```

I am unable to establish the connection but when I try like below:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 4443
```

and then try to access via browser I get below error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to mybox.com:4443. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

I aim to make a simple HTTPS server. Please let me know how can I fix the issue?
======================= updates =================================

I copied the key.pem file to cert.pem

```
cat key.pem >> cert.pem
```

Now when I bring up my server :

```
python ./try.py
```

and Hit URL

```
https://mybox.com:15368/
```

I see browser states "**Connected to mybox.com:4443**" but keeps waiting for a responding page. While at box I see below ouput:

```
# python try.py
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

I need to keep entering the same pass phrase which I used while creating the the cert and pem files

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have mybox.com setup in your hosts file, but you need to include the port. HTTPS tries to access 443 by default. You need to specify the port

HTTPS: //mybox.com:4443

Comment: Yes its there in /etc/hosts file and accessing the same way https://mybox.com:4443 - Updated my question

Comment: for your certfile location should you include the '.' for current directory or is it actually in the root?
certfile='./myhome/cert.pem'

Comment: The path is correct only I have used both absolute and relative path

Comment: if you include -nodes in your openssl command to create the key does it still ask for a passphrase? --From the comments on the page you linked to
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout server.pem -out server.pem -days 365 -nodes

Answer (score -1):

Please change your last second line as following -  add keyfile and try again. It works on my side (ubuntu, python2.7)

```
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='cert.pem', server_side=True, **keyfile="key.pem"**)
```

Comment: File "try.py", line 6
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='cert.pem', server_side=True, **keyfile="key.pem"**)
                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb  7 2013, 12:12:45)

Comment: hi my python version is Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)